# Blazor StateHasChanged() doesnt update global class values on page

Tags: c#, events, data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side

So im trying to implement a multi-site server-side blazor application that has two services implemented as singletons like this:

```
            services.AddSingleton<MQTTService>();
            services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<MQTTService>());

            services.AddSingleton<DataCollectorService>();
            services.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DataCollectorService>());
```

The MQTT Service is connecting to the broker and managing the subscriptions and stuff, while the DataCollectorService subscribes to an event from the MQTT Service to be notified when a new message arrives. The business logic with the received data is then happening within the DataCollectorService, stuff like interpreting the topic and the payload of the mqtt message. If its valid, the DataCollectorService stores the Data in a (example) global static class:

```
            if (mqtt.IsTopic(topic, MQTTService.TopicDesc.FirstTopic))
            {
                if(topic.Contains("Data1"))
                {
                    if(topic.Contains("Temperature"))
                    {
                        DataCenter.Data1.Temperature= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message, 0, message.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The DataCenter is just a static class in the namespace:

```
    public static class DataCenter
    {
        public static DataBlock Data1 = new DataBlock();
        public static DataBlock Data2 = new DataBlock();

        public static string SetMode;

        public class DataBlock
        {
            public string Temperature { get; set; }
            public string Name{ get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My Goal with this approach is that every different page in my project can just bind these global variables to show them.

The first problem that occurs then is that obviously the page is not aware of the change if the DataCollectorService updates a variable. Thats why i implemented a notifying event for the pages, which can then call StateHasChanged. So my examplePage "Monitor" wants to just show all these values and injects the DataCollectorService:

```
@page "/monitor"
@inject DataCollectorService dcs

<MudText>DataBlock Data1: @DataCenter.Data1.Temperature/ Data2: @DataCenter.Data2.Temperature</MudText>


@code
{
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            dcs.OnRefresh += OnRefresh;
        }

        void OnRefresh()
        {
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnRefresh CALLED");
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }
}
```

This actually works, but adds a new problem to the table, everytime i switch to my monitor site again a NEW OnRefresh Method gets hooked to the Action and that results in multiple calls of "OnRefresh". I find this behaviour rather logical, cuz i never delete an "old" OnRefresh Method from the Action when I'm leaving the site, cuz i dont know WHEN i leave the site.
Thinking about this problem i came up with a solution:

```
            if (!dcs.IsRegistered("monitor"))
            {
                dcs.OnRefresh += OnRefresh;
                dcs.RegisterSubscription("monitor");
            }
```

I wrapped the action subscription with a system that registers token whenever the handler is already correctly assigned. the problem now: the variables on the site dont refresh anymore!

And thats where i'm not sure how to understand whats going on anymore. If i keep it like in the first example, so just adding dcs.OnRefresh += OnRefresh; and letting it "stack up", it actually works - because there is always a "new" and "correctly" bound method which, in my limited understanding, has the correct context.

if i forbid this behaviour i only have an somehow "old" method connected which somehow cant execute the StateHasChanged correctly. But i dont know why.

I'm not sure if i could:

1. "Change" the context of the Invoke Call so that StateHasChanged works again?
2. Change the way I register the Action Handling method

I'm additionally confused as to why the first way seems to call the method multiple times. Because if its not able to correctly call StateHasChanged() in the old method, why can it be called in the first place?

I would very much appreciate some input here, googling this kind of stuff was rather difficult because i dont know the exact root of the problem.

Comment: An addendum to @HenkHolterman's answer below.  Your `monitor` page - actually a component - is managed by the `Renderer`.  When it goes out of scope the `Renderer` runs dispose.  So if I read your question correctly, by using the approach in the answer, you no longer need to worrying about managing the registered event handlers.  It's all managed for you.  What you've implemented is a version of what is know as the **Notification Pattern** used extensively in Blazor applications to signal changes in data services to components.

Comment: So you believe that implementing the IDisposable interface will solve the issue ?

Comment: @enet - when you rarely see more than 20% of the code and a partial picture of the context you can never be sure of anything.  Make a suggestion, see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only do you have multiple calls, you also have a memory leak. The event subscription will prevent the Monitor object to be collected.

Make the page IDisposable:

```
@page "/monitor"
@inject DataCollectorService dcs
@implements IDisposable

...

@code
{

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
      dcs.OnRefresh += OnRefresh;
   }

   ...

   public void Dispose()
   {
     dcs.OnRefresh -= OnRefresh;
   }
}
```